# Primary key versus key

Tags: mysql, primary-key, key

When creating a mysql dump containing the structure of my database, one of the tables shows the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `completedTransactions` (
  `paymentId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(15) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `actionTaken` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `response` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `responseCode` int(5) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY  (`paymentId`,`timestamp`),
  KEY `paymentId` (`paymentId`),
```

The primary key is what I was expecting, but I'm unsure what the last line is about?

```
KEY `paymentId` (`paymentId`),
```

Is this related to an index?

Comment: I wonder why, in this very case, an additional index is created on paymentId, since the primary key should be an index as well.
So, imho, the additional index (key) is obsolete.

Comment: @Frederik: The primary key is a compound key and so its index will be based on that. When searching just on the basis of a `paymentId`, that index may not be useful.

Comment: @Frederik Gheysels: As both `paymentId` and `timestamp` belong to the primary key, an index is created over both fields. So it is ok to create an extra index for `paymentId`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: It looks like the order of the primary key's composite index implies that a query on `paymentId` could still use that index efficiently, without needing the additional index.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I do not agree.  Since paymentId is the first column in the compound primary key, that index will still be used when you search just on paymentId.
It would be more beneficial to add an additional query on timestamp (if there are queries that filter on that column), since, when searching on timestamp, then the index that exists on the PK can't be used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the `KEY` keyword is just an alias for the `INDEX` keyword.

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
  ...
  {INDEX|KEY} [index_name] [index_type] (index_col_name,...)
      [index_option] ...
```

Source: [MySQL Documentation: CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

Answer (score 3):

`KEY` is not unique, `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE KEY` are uniques.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the documentation of [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html) :

> `KEY` is normally a synonym for `INDEX`.
>   
> The key attribute `PRIMARY KEY` can also
>   be specified as just `KEY` when given in
>   a column definition. This was
>   implemented for compatibility with
>   other database systems.